# Regex Match only if group contains another character

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match time that contains a `:` and a `.` but can also be empty.

For example:

```
Match:
No Match: 5.564
Match: 1:23.321
Match: 12:02.213
No Match: 59.999
```

I have:

```
([0-9:\.]*)
```

But I'm not sure how to make sure that IF it does match, it also contains a :

Comment: Maybe `\d+:\d+\.\d+` or `^(?:\d+:\d+\.\d+)?$` will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
'^\d+:\d{2}\.\d{3}$|^$'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dates = ['','5.564','1:23.321','12:02.213','59.999']
def check_date(dates):
    for date in dates:
        if (not date) or ('.' in date and ':' in date):
             yield date
list(check_date(dates))
>>>['', '1:23.321', '12:02.213']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ['', '5.564', ' 1:23.321', ' 12:02.213', ' 59.999']
new_s = filter(lambda x:bool(re.findall('\.\w+:|:\w+\.|^$', x)), s)
```

Output:

```
['', ' 1:23.321', ' 12:02.213']
```

tests:

```
s = [['Match', ''], ['No Match', '5.564'], ['Match', ' 1:23.321'], ['Match', ' 12:02.213'], ['No Match', ' 59.999']]
for a, b in s:
   assert (a == 'Match')  == bool(re.findall('\.\w+:|:\w+\.|^$', b))
print('passed')
```

Output:

```
passed
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexing can actually be slower than simple python in some occasions.

Here is a python function to check your matching (given you know it's a time):

```
def acceptable_time(test_value):
   return test_value == '' or \
               '.' in test_value and ':' in test_value
```

I'll performance test this against regex later.